# Отправка переменных в PHP скрипт

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Есть страница index.php

```
echo $var1;
echo $var2;
echo "<a href='script.php'>Ссылка</a>"
```

И есть скрипт script.php, который использует PhpWord библиотеку

```
$section->addText(htmlspecialchars('Код производителя: '), 'rStyle');
$section->addText(htmlspecialchars('Цена производителя: '), 'rStyle');
```

И автоматом формирует word-документ и предлагает сохранить его у клиента.
Т.е я нажимаю на ссылку и вылетает окошко с предложением сохранить файл.
У меня возник вопрос как можно передать переменные `$var1 $var2`  в этот скрипт что бы он смог сохранить их содержимое в word-документ?
Что то типа такой функции?

```
function set_document(){
            var link = "{$var1;}";
            var value = "{$var2;}";

            jQuery.ajax({
                url:'script.php'
                , type:'POST'
                , data:{name:value, link:link }
                , success: function(response) {

                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: $section->addText(htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]), 'rStyle');

Comment: "<a href='script.php'>Ссылка</a> onclick='set_document()'" - так к сожалению не работает - файл не скачивается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно для этого отправить форму:

**index.php**

```
<?php
$var1 = json_encode(['var' => 'one']);
$var2 = json_encode(['var' => 'one']);
?>

<form id="target" action="script.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="link" value='<?php echo $var1; ?>'>
    <input type="hidden" name="value" value='<?php echo $var2; ?>'>
</form>

<a id="download" href="#">Скачать</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $("#download").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#target').submit();
        });
    });

</script>
```

---

**script.php**

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    echo 'wrong request';
    exit;
}
$link = isset($_POST['link']) ? json_decode($_POST['link'], true): '';
$value = isset($_POST['value']) ? json_decode($_POST['value'], true): '';

//Работа с файлом
//...
```

Comment: спасибо, обязательно попробую

Comment: $("#download").on("click", function (e) { - ругается на эту строчку "Uncaught type error $(..) on is not a function" - я не особо шарю в jquery.

Comment: попробовал без функции, все отработало, спасибо тебе большое.

Comment: @votanko Пожалуйста, рад помочь. Ошибка могла возникнуть из-за старой версии jQuery < 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Можно так как Вы описали, а можно записать их в сессию а в файле script.php достать из сессии.

Ну например так `$_SESSION['var1'] = $var1;`, а в файле script.php так `$var = $_SESSION['var1'];` и все можете пихать куда угодно.

Comment: Cессию пробовал, таких страниц много - неудобно отслеживать какая часть сессии за какую стр отвечает.

Comment: А просто post или get запросом передать?
например get <a href='script.php?var1=LALALA&var2=ALALA'>Ссылка</a>

а в script.php 

$var1 = GET['var1']; ну и так далее

Comment: 4 переменных, и они по объему большие. Как вариант, ид-ки передать так,  а в скрипте данные из бд тянуть, но это в крайнем случае.

Comment: Почему крайний, так и надо делать.

Comment: В index.php эти переменные уже получены из бд, т.е мне надо еще раз делать запрос к бд, чтобы получить их в script.php - ну это как то не по феншую